# Arrayformula to increment value

Tags: google-sheets

Basically, I'm trying to increment a value based on the same column with a criteria.
The initial seed is 1 and it should pick up from there.
From the first row that is blank on column C, it should then increment the value by 1. The only exception would be from 12 to 13, that it would then start over from 1.

I've tried using arrayformula with this, but it doesn't work due to interative calculation issues.
Is there any way to make this work?

[image: Expected result]

Comment: I can show you how to do this with an Arrayformula if you share a small editable sample sheet of some sort.  it's tough to demo in the abstract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in B2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C="",,MOD(COUNTIFS(C2:C,"",ROW(C2:C),"<="&ROW(C2:C)),12)+1))
```

Answer (score -1):

Does it needs to be an array formula?

You can paste into `B3` `=if(ISBLANK(C3),B2+1,if(B2=12,1,B2))` and then drag it down the rest of the column.